# Como crear una variable de sesión arreglo en webstorage?

Tags: javascript, session, local-storage

Hola he creado un sessionStorage de tipo arreglo pero no la logro identificar dado a que el nombre es genérico, si creo otro sessionStorage haria referencia al mismo. El código es el siguiente:

Primer Javascript guardo mi arreglo de sesión

```
sessionStorage.setItem(i,types[i][j].precio);
```

Segundo Javascript recupero mi arreglo de sesión

```
tabla.each(function(){
 var pre = sessionStorage.key(au);
 var valorprecio = sessionStorage.getItem(pre);
au++;
}
```

El código anterior me funciona, sin embargo necesito otro arreglo de sesión e identificar cada arreglo por un nombre, mas o menos así

```
sessionStorage['precio'].setItem(i,types[i][j].precio); 
sessionStorage['idroom'].setItem(i,types[i][j].idroom);
```

Sin embargo no se si esto sea correcto y de ser correcto como podria llamar a cada arreglo para almacenarlo en distintas variables en mi otro javascript.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Busca un poco antes de preguntar. Ayer [respondí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44239/por-qu%C3%A9-localstorage-solo-me-guarda-un-elemento-de-un-objeto-json/44243#44243) una pregunta similar que puede serte de ayuda.

> Primer Javascript guardo mi arreglo de sesión: `sessionStorage.setItem(i,types[i][j].precio);`

Lo anterior no es del todo correcto. Las claves de `Storage`, que es donde se guardan los pares, **deben ser `strings`**. Supongo que en tu ejemplo, la variable `i` es un entero. Puedes ver ésto en detalle [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem).

> necesito otro arreglo de sesión e identificar cada arreglo por un nombre, mas o menos así: `sessionStorage['precio'].setItem(i,types[i][j].precio)`

No hagas eso, no es buena práctica. Si necesitas tener varias entradas, en su lugar guarda objetos javascript.

```
let data = {
  precio: 4875.25,
  idroom: 'sdfafdn'
};

sessionStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
```

De ésta manera, puedes buscar llaves y valores de la manera tradicional, iterando el objeto. Para recuperar la data, solo debes convertir el JSON guardado en forma de string a objeto JavaScript:

```
let data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data'));
```

Comment: Si efectivamente, la variable i es un entero.